# FluentValidation for simple/scalar type string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation for complex type validation on POST actions. Is it possible to use the same framework to validate simple/scalar types like DataAnnotations does with Attributes on parameters for GET actions?

```
    [HttpGet("{code}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetByCode(
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 8)]         //DataAnnotation <-------
        [FromRoute]
        string code
        )
    {
    .........
```

I would like to use just one validation framework instead of use DataAnnotations too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically with regard to FluentValidation, the library isn't designed for this.  Jeremy (the author) specifically addressed this question in a GitHub issue that asked something similar to what you're asking.  He basically said FV isn't designed for this (https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/337).  You're going to need to stick to attributes for simple validation of simple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can introduce

```
public class RequestDto
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

and then bind this dto using [`FromQueryAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute) in controller action method

FluentValidation will be able to validate the `RequestDto` when corresponding validator is registered